# Get wrong calculation for mean and standard deviation

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation using following
code segment. I am not getting any compile errors.
When I run it using `.txt` file, the output
appears following way:

```
"
"is not a valid integer
```

with wrong summation, mean and standard deviation and also `Can't input double values`.

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

      if(buffer == NULL)
      {

      }

      double result = fread(buffer,1,lSize,file);
      if(result != lSize){

      }
      else{

        char *str = strtok(buffer," ,");

        int count = 0;
        while(str != NULL){
          double val = (int) strtol(str,&str,10);

          if(*str != ' ' && *str != '\0')
          {


          }
          else{

            if(count == 0)
            {

              root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
              root->next = NULL;
              root->value = val; 
              current = root;
              count++;

            }
            else{

              double x = createNode(current,val);      
            }
          }

          str = strtok(NULL," ,");
        }

      }
      current = root;
      printf("Sum is %lf and link count is %lf\n",
             getSummation(current), getNodeCount(current));

      double mean = getMean(getSummation(current),getNodeCount(current));
      double stdev = getStandardDeviation(root, mean,getNodeCount(current));



      fclose( file );
      free(buffer);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


int createNode(struct node *n,double val)
{
  if(n != NULL){
    while(n->next != NULL)
    {
      n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n = n -> next;
    n -> value = val;
    n -> next = NULL;
  }
  return 1;
}

int getSummation(struct node *element){
  double sum = 0.0f;
  if(element != NULL)
  {
    while(element != NULL)
    {
      sum = sum + element->value;
      element= element->next;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Null Point Exception thrown");
  }
  return sum;
}

int getNodeCount(struct node *link)
{
  int count = 0;

  while(link != NULL)
  {

  }

  return count;
}

double getMean(double summation,int numberOfNodes)
{

}

double getStandardDeviation(struct node *link, double mean,int linkCount)
{


  while(link != NULL)
  {

  }

  stdev = sqrt((diffrenceSummation)/(linkCount - 1));
   return stdev;
}
```

Comment: Likely the file ends with a `\n` and that fails `if(*str != ' ' && *str != '\0')`.  Change the tokenizing and `if()` to tolerate all whitespace.

Comment: Amongst other problems, `getStandardDeviation()` does not contain a `return` statement.  If your compiler is not giving you any warnings, you need to fix your compiler options so you get basic warnings about that sort of issue, or you need to get a better compiler. If you're using GCC, use at least `gcc -Wall`; preferably, `gcc -Wall -Wextra` (and I use more stringent warnings than that).

Comment: Too long. Way too long. Also, you have a couple of superfluous, ugly casts. Neither `(char *)malloc` nor `(int)strtol` are needed.

Comment: Suggest posting an example .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add prototypes before `main()`

```
//double getSummation(struct node*element);
int getSummation(struct node *element);
int createNode(struct node *n,double val);
int getNodeCount(struct node *link);
#include <math.h>
```

2) Use consistent format specifiers

```
  //printf("Summation is %lf and link count is %lf\n", 
  //  getSummation(current), getNodeCount(current));
  printf("Summation is %d and link count is %d\n",
       getSummation(current), getNodeCount(current));
```

3) Various castings are questionable

```
// mean = (double)summation/(double)numberOfNodes;
mean = summation/numberOfNodes;
// double linkValue = (double) link->value;
double linkValue = link->value;
// buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
buffer = malloc(lSize);
// double val = (int) strtol(str,&str,10);
double val = strtol(str,&str,10);
```

Comment: i did the changes according to your code segment still it appears  ,is not a valid integer

Comment: once I input 10 real numbers it appears in valid integer and then link count is 9,it calculate summation by adding only nine numbers,Can't input double values.if anyone can give a help.

Comment: the values i added to a text file in this way 160 591 114 229 230 270 128 1657 624 1503

Comment: any help plz.for mean i got 444.777778 and standard deviation is 492.072347 expected value is mean550.6 and standard deviation 572.03

Comment: @user3283912 That is becasue your input file has `"1503\n"` rather than `"1503"` or `"1503 "`.

Comment: @user3283912 Change the input file or add to `if(*str != ' ' && *str != '\0')` and `strtok(buffer," ,")` the ability to check for `'\n'`.

Comment: Be sure to have all your compiler warnings enabled.  Some of the issues would  certainly have been shown there and saved you time.  Good luck.